Android: Conversation notifications update pattern
We're using NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle for some push-notifications in our Android app. Notifications are recieved via OneSignal SDK, and we implement INotificationServiceExtension to mutate them, including the aforementioned MessagingStyle.
When we receive a new message notification, we want to add the new message to an existing notification if it exists, otherwise display a new one.
Currently this requires fetching the old notification by its locusId, copying its style, canceling it and displaying a new one with the new message added. I am not sure if it's the correct way. I should also mention that no notification ids are tracked, they are auto-generated by OneSignal.
Here's a simplified implementation of INotificationServiceExtension:
class PushNotificationService : INotificationServiceExtension {
    override fun onNotificationReceived(event: INotificationReceivedEvent) {
        when (val type = event.notification.additionalData?.getString("type")) {
            "new_message" -> {
                // Can't be null if type exists
                val data: NewMessagePushData = event.notification.additionalData!!.let {
                    Json.decodeFromString(it.toString())
                }
                event.applyConversationStyle(data)
            }
            // ...
        }
    }

    private fun INotificationReceivedEvent.applyConversationStyle(
        data: NewMessagePushData
    ) {
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(FirebaseMessagingService.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)
                as NotificationManager
        val previousNotification = notificationManager
            .activeNotifications
            .find {
                it.notification.locusId?.id == data.chatId.toString()
            }
        val usersDao = getService(context).usersDao()
        notification.setExtender { notification ->
            val (user, icon) = runBlocking {
                val user = /* Fetch user from local DB*/
                val icon = user?.let {/*Fetch user's avatar and process it for display*/}
                user to icon
            }
            if (user == null) return@setExtender notification

            val person = /*Build an androidx.core.app.Person from user data*/

            val style = previousNotification?.let {
                NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.extractMessagingStyleFromNotification(it.notification)
            } ?: NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(
                /*Build an androidx.core.app.Person for current user*/
            )
            
            // This is questionable!
            previousNotification?.id?.let {
                OneSignal.Notifications.removeNotification(it)
            }


            notification
                .setContentTitle(user.fullName.asString(context))
                .setStyle(
                    style
                        .addMessage(
                            NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message(
                                data.body,
                                System.currentTimeMillis(),
                                person
                            )
                        )
                )
                .addPerson(person)
                .setLargeIcon(icon?.toIcon(context))
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setLocusId(LocusIdCompat(data.chatId.toString()))
                .setShortcutInfo(context.createConversationShortcutIfNeeded(
                    data = data,
                    user = user,
                    person = person,
                    icon = icon
                ))
        }
    }
}

What is the correct and standard way of doing what I want? Should I bring my messages DAO into this service to fetch messages? Should I ask the backend team to keep track of notification ids and send the same ones for any particular conversation so the system auto-mutates them for me? Or should I keep track of those ids myself?

Btw, this solution kinda breaks when OneSignal restores notifications after app kill. Each message becomes its own conversation. Could this be because their ids are different?

Related issue: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/2114
